# I have no idea what below surface equation represent

Tags: quadratics

I have the equation:

$$x^2+y^2+4z^2-14xy+8xz-8yz=24$$

What does this equation represent?

How can I find the "axes" of it (?), and is it possible to draw it when it intersect the plane $z=0$?

Comment: Probably, the best thing is to the Lagrange method

Comment: @Arteom or GRAPHER :)

Comment: Can you write down something in concrete ?

Comment: @ monday25: WolframAlpha is your friend. Put the equation in this search engine and you will figure out that this is a hyperbolic cylinder

Comment: Find the Hessian matrix of the quadratic form. The eigenvalues and the eigenvectors, the latter being your axes (normalized to unit length if required), are about as easy as these can ever get, someone put a fair amount of effort into constructing this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Complete the square.

As a short example $$x^2  - 14xy = (x - 7y)^2 - 49y^2$$

Answer (score 2):

This is the equation of a quadric surface. It corresponds to a quadratic form $q(x,y,z)$ which can be represented by the symmetric matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-7&4\\-7&1&-4\\4&-4&4\end{bmatrix}$$
To find the axes of the quadric, you have to write its equation in normalised form, as sum of squares of linear form (*Gauß's reduction*): if
$$q(x,y,z)=\lambda_1 \ell_1^2(x,y,z)+\lambda_2 \ell_2^2(x,y,z)+\lambda_3 \ell_3^2(x,y,z)$$
is the reduced form (here we obtain the sum of the squares of $3$ forms), the equations of the axes are simply $\ell_i^2(x,y,z)=\ell_j^2(x,y,z)=0$ for all pairs $i\neq j$.
The type of quadric surface is determined by the *signature* of the quadratic form, wwhich the pair $(p,q)$, where $p$ is the number of squares of linear forms with a positive coefficient, and $q$ the number of forms with a negative coefficient. It is also the number of positive and negative eigenvalues.

Here, the characteristic polynomial is $-x^3+6x^2+72x\,$ and the eigenvalues are $12,-6,0$. The eigenvectors are, respectively:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

In this (orthogonal) basis the matrix of the quadratic form is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}12&0&0\\0&-6&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
hence the equation of the surface is $\,36X^2-6Y^2=24\iff \dfrac32X^2-\dfrac14Y^2=1$, which is the equation of a *hyperbolic cylinder*.